# get data from mongodb in match condition

Tags: mongodb, find, cursor

I have data.
condition is: valid home count > 0 (valid home means deleted not true)

```
{
    "_id": 998e58,
　　"home": [
　　　　{
　　　　　"home_id": 433667,
　　　　　"deleted": true
　　　　},
　　　　{
　　　　　"home_id": 488742,
　　　　　"deleted": ""
　　　　},
　　　　{
　　　　　"home_id": 479331,
　　　　　"deleted": true
　　　　},
　　　　{
　　　　　"home_id": 481125,
　　　　},
　]
},
{
    "_id": 889g45,
　　"home": [
　　　　{
　　　　　"home_id": 934456,
　　　　　"deleted": true
　　　　},
　　　　{
　　　　　"home_id": 978646,
　　　　　"deleted": true
　　　　},
　]
},
```

because:
"_id": 998e58, it's total home count = 4, not valid home = 2, so valid home count is 4-2 = 2, it bigger than 0.  --> **match**
"_id": 889g45, it's total home count = 2, not valid home = 2, so valid home count is 2-2 = 0, it equal 0.  --> **not match**

so, if data match condition(means valid home count >0).
**How can I use mongodb condtion to achieve my goal?**
BTW, The number of my device may be tens of thousands, therefore if use unwind, groupby...
It may exceed the memory limit. ORZ.

I hope when I write command: db.colletion_name.find(...),
I will get data:

```
{
    "_id": 998e58,
　　"home": [
　　　　{
　　　　　"home_id": 488742,
　　　　　"deleted": ""
　　　　},
　　　　{
　　　　　"home_id": 481125,
　　　　},
　]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first we use `filter` to find all elements that deleted is not true

then we `addFields` to add size of newHome array as number

and after that we `match` doc with size > 0

and then `project` to create expected output

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
      {
          $project:{
              newHome:{
              $filter :{
                  input:"$home",
                  as:"z",
                  cond:{$ne:["$$z.deleted",true]}
              }
          }
        }
      },
      {
          $addFields:{
              numOfActive : {$size:"$newHome"}
          }
      },
      {
          $match:{numOfActive:{$gt:0}}
      },
      {project:{
          _id:1,
          home:"$newHome"
      }}
  ])
```